# Unattended Installation Ubuntu 20.04 Server via VirtualBox

Tags: server, system-installation, virtualbox, 20.04, preseed

I was making today scripts for automated VirtualBox installation via VBoxManage.
The main goal is to install a VirtualMachine without any prompting.
So I made the some scripts for the Desktop Ubuntu distributions 18.04 and 20.04 and everything worked fine.

Everything worked perfectly, u just run it and it installs from start to end without any prompting.

However, when I wanted to do the same with the Ubuntu Server distributions (18.04 and 20.04), the installation process started prompting for user input such as language, username, pw etc, even all the information was provided in the preseeds.cfg. Am I missing here something?

Seems like the installation ignores the input from the preseeds.

I couldnt find any information on this, except that some people made a patch fix on the .cfg files and tried to solve the problem, which in my case didnt change anything.

I will try to make a custom .iso file, but I am curious why this approach is not working?

Has anyone solved this issue? Is there a way to force the usage of a certain preseed file? Thanks in advance

Comment: I've already provided a way [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1544921/vboxmanage-unattended-ubuntu-live-server/1545412#1545412)

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole section of http://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall on this topic.

The short answer:

- The DESKTOP installer (*ubiquity*) is based upon debian-installer, and you use a preseed file
- The SERVER installer (*subiquity*) is no longer based upon d-i, and you use a subsection of the existing cloud-config file. Different format: It uses YAML.

Here's the important bit:

> ## Differences from debian-installer preseeding
>
> *preseeds* are the way to automate an installer based on debian-installer (aka d-i).
>
> autoinstalls for the new server installer differ from preseeds in the following main ways:
>
> - the format is completely different (cloud-init config, usually yaml, vs debconf-set-selections format)
> - when the answer to a question is not present in a preseed, d-i stops and asks the user for input. autoinstalls are not like this: by default, if there is any autoinstall config at all, the installer takes the default for any unanswered question (and fails if there is no default).
>
>   - You can designate particular sections in the config as “interactive”, which means the installer will still stop and ask about those.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info. I will definitely try that one out. But shouldn’t the server version 18.04 at least work? Or is it generally a subiquity installation for all newer server distributions?

Comment: 18.04 Server also used Subiquity. It's been around for a few years.

Comment: Reading this autoinstall documentation I'm not getting how to build customized install media with it.

I mean, the quicksetup example show how to make a seed ISO and a disk file and start a VM in KVM. 

But I need to build a .iso to create USB sticks for physical computers. I don't see how to do that in the documentation for `autoinstall`. What am I missing?

Comment: @CarstenAgger Check out https://superuser.com/a/1545412 for a working example of one way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, there's also this using a no `nocloud` directory in the ISO itself.